# Drawing shape and flicker

Tags: .net, winforms, c++-cli

i'm trying to use MouseMove to redraw the same rectangle in a new position inside the panel it works, but i'm having alot of flicker from Invalidate... i tried Refresh (), but it the same... please help me

this is my code for drawing inside the panel with MouseMove event:

```
if (panel->BackgroundImage == nullptr)
{
    panel->BackgroundImage = gcnew System::Drawing::Bitmap(panel->Width, panel->Height);
}

Graphics^ buffGraphics = Graphics::FromImage(panel->BackgroundImage);

buffGraphics->Clear(panel->BackColor);
buffGraphics->DrawRectangle(System::Drawing::Pens::Blue,10, 10, 50, 50);

panel->Invalidate();
panel->Update();
```

Comment: Why don't you just draw directly onto the panel inside of its `Paint` event handler?

Comment: Becouse i'm new into this and dont know how, but maybe you could show me, please :)

Answer (score 0):

add onForm load method to your Form and enable double buffering as:

```
DoubleBuffered = true;
```

or if you want an alternative way to do that is to go the Form design View 
right click on the form and click on Properties then search for the **DoubleBuffered**
property and set it to true

Also, any drawing should be on Paint event

Answer (score -1):

It [looks like](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db8dsek8%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) `Graphics->CopyFromScreen()` might help

Comment: Could you please show me compelete example how to implant it right? please